# What are the two flashing dots on Italian train station boards?

Tags: trains, italy, tips-and-tricks, train-stations

I am currently in Italy, and I have witnessed something that is occurring at all non-metro train stations.

At any given time, there will be two dots flashing on the first (by departure times) few trains in the departure boards and on the respective information LCD on the respective platforms. And I'm having difficulties knowing what it is supposed to represent.

[Video of the lights](https://nx.test124.fr/s/Ni7bPpfHymeWnFF)

Since this is always happening very near departure time and on every train in this situation, I have the theory that this is a *last call*-like message to indicate imminent departure or to indicate that doors have closed, but I wasn't able to get a clear answer from my research in both French and English.

Comment: There used to be a very similar display on departure boards in airports (before they were replaced by CRT or LCD screens). IIRC in airports it meant “boarding”.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the link to the video has died due to link rot. However, I assume you mean the dots to the right of this list of trains departing (for example) from Roma Termini:

[image: Train Departure Display at Roma Termini]
<sup>[File:Tabellone delle partenze Roma Tiburtina 01.JPG](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tabellone_delle_partenze_Roma_Tiburtina_01.JPG)CC Attribution 3.0</sup>

Blinking dots indicate that the train is departing (*in partenza*, in Italian). This is replicated in the digital version of the departing train dashboard, which [can be found at this link](https://iechub.rfi.it/ArriviPartenze/ArrivalsDepartures/Monitor?Arrivals=False&Search=termini&PlaceId=2416):
[image: Departing train online dashboard for Roma Termini]

I cannot say whether this means that the train is closing its doors, is about to depart, or has departed from the platform.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it means "boarding now" (train is there and doors are open).  Once the train departs, it's no longer listed.